# Laravel not publishing to Redis

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I am trying to implement Redis publishing in my local RESTful API which is built in Laravel for the purposes of implementing a chat system later on with Web Sockets. I intend to read them from a Node.JS server later on.

I am using `Redis::publish` to publish a simple message to my `test-channel`.
However, for some reason Laravel doesn't seem to publish to it.
I have also noticed that when I call `Redis::set`, whatever I set doesn't get persisted in Redis, but using `Redis::get` I can read the values that I'm setting.

```php
public function redis(Request $request) {
    $data = $request->validate([
        'message' => 'string|required'
    ]);

    Redis::publish('test-channel', 'a test message');

    return 'Done';
}
```

I am using the code above in the `api/redis` route:

```php
Route::post('/redis', 'API\MessageController@redis');
```

I have subscribed to the `test-channel` using the `redis-cli` command.
If I manually publish a message to the `test-channel` using the `redis-cli` in a terminal instance, I properly receive the messages that I am publishing. However, they don't seem to get published with Laravel for some reason.

What I can notice while running `php artisan serve` and visiting the aforementioned route is Laravel logging the following:

```
[*timestamp*] 127.0.0.1:39448 Accepted
[*timestamp*] 127.0.0.1:39448 Closing
```

The port after `127.0.0.1` appears to be random.

I tried both php-redis php extension and the predis package, just to be sure that it isn't any one of them, but I get the same result with both of them. I am currently using php-redis with both igbinary and redis extensions enabled in `/etc/php/config.d` and have removed the Redis alias from `config/app.php`.
I am using PHP 7.4, Laravel 6.0 and Redis 5.0.7 on Manjaro.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Been there, discovered that with:

```
$ redis-client
psubscribe *
```

will show you what's going on.

Chances are that your default config/database.php contains something like:

```
    'redis' => [

    'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
        'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
    ],
```

In that case, the channel name will be prefixed with this prefix option.
So you can just comment this option, or, if you keep it, be sure to subscribe to the right channel

```
Redis::publish('test-channel', 'a test message');

$prefix = config('database.redis.options.prefix');
$channel = $prefix . 'test-channel';

return "Done. (published on $channel)";
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me solve it - it was the prefix that I was missing.